# Python Boolean array set index value of True to 0

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have an array:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

And then I have a Boolean array

```
b = np.array([False, False, True, True, True])
```

I would like the values of 'True' in b to make the values in a = 0, otherwise, retain the values of a. In other words, I want something like:

```
c = a[b]
```

except this deletes any instances of 'False'. I would want the answer to be [1,2,0,0,0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(b, 0, a)
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify `a` in place, assigning to `a` indexed by the boolean array of matching length only replaces the values that are `True`:

```
>>> a[b] = 0
>>> a
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

`~` inverts a boolean array, so it's trivial to replace where the values are `False` instead:

```
>>> a[~b] = 0  # Assume we reinitialized a to the original state
>>> a
array([0, 0, 3, 4, 5])
```